# Asignar permiso de lectura a una tabla de una base de datos diferente a la predetermianada sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día,

Cree un usuario en sql server 2008 como base de datos prdeterminada le puse compras, ahora necesito agregar permiso de lectura de una tabla en especifico que esta en otra base de datos llamada clientes, lo intente desde la seccion de securables pero solo me muestra tablas de mi base de datos compras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé cuál es la sección de *securables*, pero los permisos los puedes asignar mediante sentencias DDL, en este caso precisas de construir una sentencia [`grant`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para otorgar el privilegio `select`, que le permitiría *leer* la información de la tabla, pero no modificarla, por ejemplo, la siguiente instrucción:

```
grant select on clientes.dbo.nombreDeTabla to nombreDeUsuario;
```

Estoy asumiendo que la tabla está en el esquema `dbo`, si es otro, ajusta la sentencia.

La instrucción la tienes que ejecutar con un usuario que sea administrador del esquema `dbo` (o el que contenga la tabla) de la base de datos `clientes`. Para ser técnicamente correcto, la tiene que ejecutar un usuario que tenga por lo menos el permiso `select with grant option` sobre la tabla de marras.

Esta instrucción puedes lanzarla de manera interactiva valiéndote del *SQL Server Management Studio*, o desde cualquier *programa* que permita la ejecución de sentencias SQL.